# Шрифт отображается по разному у одинаковых кнопок

Tags: html, css, шрифты

Имеется верстка в которой есть элемент кнопка, создаю абсолютно идентичные элементы в разных частях страницы, но в одной кнопке шрифт жирный, а в другой тот, который нужен

Вот первая кнопка: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот вторая кнопка: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кнопки ближе:

Жирность: 300

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Жирность: 400

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код думаю тут не нужен, т.к. проблема в чем-то другом. Классы для кнопок одинаковые.

Пробовал чистить кеш в браузере, не помогло.

Comment: Код нужен, проблема именно в нем, вы не показываете как подключен сам шрифт, не показываете font-family.

Comment: @kizoso, какая разница как он подключен, если он у один работает, а у других нет, при том, что стили одинаковые везде. Проблему удалось решить уменьшением шрифта у тех кнопок, что имели жирный шрифт, возможно баг какой-то в браузере

Comment: а вас на этих кнопках различается либо шрифт либо размер, смотрите от кого что может наследовать. + возможно плывет из-за css трансформации. А вообще они обе убогие, так что никто и не заметит)

Comment: Разница есть. может у вас жирность в названии прописывается. может вы во втором случае другой шрифт тянете, можно только гадать

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать в стиле, описывающем внешний вид кнопки, указать аттрибут `font-style:normal`. Тогда у браузера будет жесткая установка не показывать текст жирным. 
Вот здесь можно посмотреть подробнее об этом: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font-style.asp

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй в DevTools перейти во вкладку *Computed* для каждой кнопки посмотри значение font-weight, если они отличаются можешь посмотреть откуда ноги растут, нажав на стрелочку открытия и оно покажет с какой часьт кода применяются стили